# how to catch/exact text in dictation.io/speech

Tags: speech-recognition

I need SPEECH TO TEXT by using dictation.io/speech.
we talk, this web will record and return a prase. So, how can i catch/exact this text to my text.txt on my computer by coding ( any programming language).
Please help, thank you so much.